# Python: Using lxml to locate text outside a span

Tags: python, css-selectors, lxml

I have to parse some HTML. However, it is malformed.. as you can see the text "Cowabunga" is not in contained in any HTML element.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector

stuff = '''<p>
                <span id="alpha" style="color: #999; "></span> 
                <span id="bravo" style="color: #999; "></span> 
                Cowabunga  
            </p>'''

l = CSSSelector ("p")

e = l(fromstring(stuff))
print e[0].text
```

How can I use lxml/Python to write a CSSSelector to locate this text?

Thanks

**Edit:** The code above gives blank output - just a row of spaces - I need to catch "Cowabunga"

Comment: That HTML is not malformed - "Cowabunga" is in the `p` element, occurring immediately after the `span`s but not within them.

Comment: yes, malformed is probably not the canonical term here -  Steven's "mixed content" seems a better term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mixed content so it's always a little rough. `e[0].text_content()` will get all of the text in your example.